# Escaping CURL @ symbol with PHP

Tags: php, curl, escaping

I'm writing a php application that submits via curl data to sign up for an iContact email list. However I keep getting an invalid email address error. I think this may be due to the fact that I'm escaping the @ symbol so it looks like %40 instead of @. Also, according to the php documentation for curl_setopt with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS:

> The full data to post in a HTTP
>   "POST" operation. To post a file,
>   prepend a  filename with @ and use the
>   full path.

So, is there anyway to pass the @ symbol as post data through curl in php without running it through urlencode first?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/http_build_query) on your data-array first before passing it to `curl_setopt()`, that will lead to it sending the form as `application/x-www-form-encoded` instead of `multipart/form-data` (and thus the @ is not interpreted).

Also why do you really care about the @ in an email-address? It only matters if the @ is the first character, not somewhere in the middle.

Comment: I have the same problem, and don't feel the answer above completely answers the question correctly.

I'm building a cURL request (in php) that can send get, post, AND files.

get variables are url encoded, no problem.One of my post variables however, contains a password. If it starts with @, it won't work. cURL thinks it's a file, but it's not. if I use http_build_query, it generates a querystring (get, but I want post for passwords!)

Is there really no way to escape the @ symbol for cURL??? Documentation doesn't exist for this, and trying various 'known' escape methods doesn't work.

Comment: @kclement, you should always post new problems as an actual question, not in a comment, since its unlikely to be seen. `http_build_query()` is not just for GET requests, if you pass the result in the message body and post it with cURL it should work.

Answer (score 5):

After search PHP curl manual, I found there is no information to escape the first ‘@’ if the post field is a string instead of a file if post with multipart/form-data encoding.

The way I worked around this problem is prefixing a blank at the beginning of the text. While our backend API will strip blanks so it could remove the blank and restore the original text. I don't know weather Twitter API will trim blanks on user input.

If so, this workaround also works for you.

If any one found the way to escaping the first '@' when using PHP curl with multipart/form-data encoding, please let us know.

Comment: See my new answer plz

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue, though with curl itself and not PHP curl.

When using curl's field option '`-F`' a leading @ symbol will not be sent in the POST but instead will instruct curl to send the file name that immediately succeeds the symbol as part of the POST.

Fortunately, curl offers another option '`--form-string`', which behaves the same way as '`-F`', except that the 'form-string' option is not parsed.

As an example, if you want to use curl to POST field1 with value "@value" and file1 with the file "testfile.txt" you can do so as follows:

```
curl "http://www.url.com" --form-string "field1=@value" -F "file1=@testfile.txt"
```

Comment: What would be the syntax of this in using PHP's cURL?

Answer (score 4):

This is the **true** solution that can support both **string containing `@`** and **files**.

#### Solution for PHP 5.6 or later:

- Use `CURLFile` instead of `@`.

#### Solution for PHP 5.5 or later:

- Enable `CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD`.
- Use `CURLFile` instead of `@`.

#### Solution for PHP 5.3 or later:

- Build up multipart content body by youself.
- Change `Content-Type` header by yourself.

The following snippet will help you :D

```
<?php

/**
 * For safe multipart POST request for PHP5.3 ~ PHP 5.4.
 * 
 * @param resource $ch cURL resource
 * @param array $assoc "name => value"
 * @param array $files "name => path"
 * @return bool
 */
function curl_custom_postfields($ch, array $assoc = array(), array $files = array()) {
    
    // invalid characters for "name" and "filename"
    static $disallow = array("\0", "\"", "\r", "\n");
    
    // initialize body
    $body = array();
    
    // build normal parameters
    foreach ($assoc as $k => $v) {
        $k = str_replace($disallow, "_", $k);
        $body[] = implode("\r\n", array(
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{$k}\"",
            "",
            filter_var($v), 
        ));
    }
    
    // build file parameters
    foreach ($files as $k => $v) {
        switch (true) {
            case false === $v = realpath(filter_var($v)):
            case !is_file($v):
            case !is_readable($v):
                continue; // or return false, throw new InvalidArgumentException
        }
        $data = file_get_contents($v);
        $v = call_user_func("end", explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $v));
        list($k, $v) = str_replace($disallow, "_", array($k, $v));
        $body[] = implode("\r\n", array(
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{$k}\"; filename=\"{$v}\"",
            "Content-Type: application/octet-stream",
            "",
            $data,
        ));
    }
    
    // generate safe boundary 
    do {
        $boundary = "---------------------" . md5(mt_rand() . microtime());
    } while (preg_grep("/{$boundary}/", $body));
    
    // add boundary for each parameters
    array_walk($body, function (&$part) use ($boundary) {
        $part = "--{$boundary}\r\n{$part}";
    });
    
    // add final boundary
    $body[] = "--{$boundary}--";
    $body[] = "";
    
    // set options
    return curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_POST       => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => implode("\r\n", $body),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Expect: 100-continue",
            "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary={$boundary}", // change Content-Type
        ),
    ));

}

?>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your amazing code. How can I use it in php < 5.3 . Because of anonymous function in `array_walk($body, function (&$part) use ($boundary)` I get T_Function error in php < 5.3. Is there anyway that part into regular function?

Comment: foreach ($body as &$part) $part = "--{$boundary}\r\n{$part}"; unset($part);

Comment: You are a brilliant programmer :) I'll credit your name in my project.

Answer (score 1):

@PatricDaryll's answer is correct, but I needed to make a bit of researches to understand where to use this [http_build_query](https://www.php.net/http_build_query) function.

To clarify and summarise, instead of doing:

```
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
```

You will use:

```
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($array));
```

Simple but confusing... curl is smart enough to understand if you gave him a string or an array.

Answer (score 0):

In order to escape the @ sign in the non-file data, you need to do the following.
Prepend the text string with the NULL character

```
$postfields = array(
    'upload_file' => '@file_to_upload.png',
    'upload_text' => sprintf("\0%s", '@text_to_upload')
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/upload-test');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```