# Using cURL to upload a file without @ symbol?

Tags: php, file, curl, upload

I have a slight problem here, how can I tell cURL specifically to attach a file to a request?

If I am uploading a file with cURL, then the common method is to attach it as part of POST data array with the value having @ in front of it, for example:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>array('my-file'=>'@my-file.txt')
```

This would obviously work, but I have two problems with it:

- What if it is not actually a file I am uploading? What if my POST value actually IS '@my-file.txt' and it attempts to upload the file instead? It creates a loophole I am desperately trying to avoid.
- How can I upload a file from a URL? Would I have to download it, store it in temporary folder and then attach it with @ from that temporary folder? Why can't I give cURL just contents that I wish to use as file?

cURL CURLOPT_INFILE is not an option, since it won't show up as part of $_FILES array.

It seems like such a loophole in cURL to be dependent on @ symbol in the POST field value. Is there a way around it? Why isn't there a CURLOPT_FILEFIELDS array? Command-line cURL has a separate flag for this (-F), but I don't see it as an option in PHP for some reason.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Re the loophole, this seems to be unfixable: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46439 you'll have to manually check fro the presence of `@` when checking input values.

Comment: Maybe [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query), as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/648296/773625)?

Comment: Thanks Pekka, I only wish there was a solution. But mAu: This doesn't work, since my API would need to support file uploads as well. Everything would be fine if it would be possible to submit files separately from POST fields and I need to submit some data in POST as well (since there are limits to GET that aren't there for POST).

Comment: @Pekka Manually checking for `@` is not a solution, because there _are_ cases where a posted value needs to start with a true, literal `@`. If you check and see that the value starts with `@`, what are your options? There's no way to post that form without triggering the upload-file mechanism, or stripping the `@` which might drastically change the semantics of the value, and if the post receiver is not under your control, you're pretty much screwed.

Comment: @lanzz I agree, but there seems to be no better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing is detecting if any of the input data started with an @ symbol and if they did, then submitting them as a GET variable (as part of the submit URL in cURL). It does not help with all cases (such as when a large string is submitted that starts with an @), but cuts out the problems I had with Twitter handles.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is viewing this in 2019 and beyond after finding this result on Google (as I have) the issue has been resolved as per [this bug fix](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46439).

You can now use CURLFile to send files via PHP CURL requests as below:

```
$fullpath = '/var/www/html/website/test.png';
$mime = 'image/png';
$publicname = 'testpic';
$cfile = curl_file_create($fullpath,$mime,$publicname);
$fields[$publicname] = curl_file_create($fullpath,$mime,$publicname);
```

Which would be then used in e.g.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

Further information can be found [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php).

Comment: Please, do not put links on answers. Try to copy the most important information here.

Comment: Sorry @KingMidas, I've just fixed this. I'm new to answering so let me know if you have any further feedback. Thanks.

Comment: Now, much better!