# Ignore @ in php cURL without encoding it

Tags: php, curl, twitter

I am sending an image and a tweet (text) to Twitter API as multipart/form-data. The image starts with '@someimagefile' and works as expected. The tweet text is something like, '@username hi.' but fails because cURL tries to interpret @username as a file path and errors out.

See answer from Wang Bin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9137917/922522

While a work-around is to prefix the tweet text with a space so the @ isn't the first char, I was wondering if there was a better way to do this? Twitter does not allow the @ sign to be encoded as anything else, https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/6663.

Is there a way to make cURL for PHP ignore the @ sign in the text (and not for the image)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried encoding the "@" in the tweet?

`str_replace('@', urlencode('@'), $tweet);`

edit: I saw your the forum post you linked and I believe he's saying it needs to be percent encoded which is what urlencode does. Have you tried what I posted above? If not give it a shot.

Comment: There's also the curl_escape() function  - but I'm not sure how it differs from rawurlencode()

Comment: I awarded the points but then realized my code hadn't updated with your change...doh! It does allow the cURL to work, but Twitter does not accept it. So when I post @screenname and percent incode the @, it shows up on twitter.com as %40screenname ... :/