# php facebook api: post "snail" char through

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook PHP API to post a image/message couple to a page.

The relevant code is:

```
$params['picture'] = realpath(str_replace(URL::site(), DOCROOT, $params['picture']));

$post_params = array(
    'access_token' => $page_token,
    'message' => $params['message'],
     'source' => '@' . $params['picture']
);

$postStream = $this->facebook->api("/" . $params['page_id'] . "/photos", 'post', $post_params);
```

The problem is that inside the message (the $params['message'] variable) sometimes a "@" char is present.
For example, I would like to post, together with my picture, the message "@something".

But this result in a Curl error: CurlException: 26: couldn't open file "something".

How can I post characters like "@" on facebook through the API?

Thanx!

Comment: Have you tried to encode that character with URL encoding?

Comment: Yes, I used "urlencode", but it results in "%40something" posted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648292/escaping-curl-symbol-with-php

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Reading it, the one way I was able to solve my problem was by prefixing my string with a blank: 'message'   =>  ' ' . $params['message']