# PHP cURL set file as POST form input type file

Tags: php, file, curl

I have a page on a different server with a `<form>` and I use cURL to set the data automatically. However in this form there is a file input `<input name='file' type='file'>` and now I am aware of the fact that the file input behaves differently from the others.

```
//This is my code till now.
$ch = curl_init();
//page is password protected I am not sure if this works but I hope it does.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://user:pass@mydomain.com/system_backup.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
//set a file as post variable this doesn't work
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "file=".$file."&var1=".$var1."&var2=".$var2);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

So my question is how do I set a file as a postfield with cURL.

Comment: See **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648292/escaping-curl-symbol-with-php/24058203#24058203)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution myself

```
$postParams['file'] = '@'.realpath("URLTOFILE.txt"); //for type = file
$postParams['var1'] = urlencode("var1"); //type = text, submit pretty much everything.

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://user:pass@mydomain.com/system_backup.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Look at this guide](http://blog.derakkilgo.com/2009/06/07/send-a-file-via-post-with-curl-and-php/), you need to prefix the file full path with '@'

Comment: This is now **deprecated** on PHP 5.5 or later. See **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648292/escaping-curl-symbol-with-php/24058203#24058203)**

Answer (score 0):

You can put the params in an array as `$postFields = array('file'=>$file,'var1'=>$var1,'var2'=>$var2);`

and then use `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($postFields));`

Hopefully should work.

Comment: the problem is that the file needs to be in the syntax of `input type='file'`