# PHP: can not uploading file with cURL. error for using @ in other fields

Tags: php, curl, telegram-bot

I'm trying to send photo to Telegram bot API using cURL but when I'm using "@" in chat_id field, I get this error: 
`Deprecated: curl_setopt_array(): The usage of the @filename API for file uploading is deprecated. Please use the CURLFile class`

Here is my code:

```
$post = array('chat_id' => '@ameer_test', 'photo'=> new CURLFile('E:\wamp\www\test/content/uploads/sample.png'));
$curl = curl_init("https://api.telegram.org/bot122877145:AAH-mTygl1FeisuOnsESbCVerRqd6-DTxD0/sendPhoto");
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    //CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD => 0,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post
    ));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($response);
```

How to tell cURL that this @ isn't filename.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you're looking for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/648292/escaping-curl-symbol-with-php

Answer (score 0):

According to php manual:

> The @ prefix can be disabled for safe passing of values beginning with @ by setting the CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD option to TRUE.